# Suddenly metro bundler showing get request for react native app

Tags: react-native

I've got a React Native app that I've upgraded to 0.57. When launching the app, I suddenly see the following GETs in the Metro bundler:

```
::1 - - [03/Feb/2019:16:29:04 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.111.98 Safari/537.36"
::1 - - [03/Feb/2019:16:29:28 +0000] "GET /assets/app/assets/icons/mainMenu/social.png?platform=ios&hash=0d29a994ae1abae62bf27bfc2281cdfa HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "myApp/2 CFNetwork/889.9 Darwin/18.2.0"
```

How can I disable those logs? Although its only matter of aesthetics, it really bothers me why it has suddenly appeared.

Comment: I noticed that when I upgraded from 0.56 to 0.57, and it appears to have continued on to 0.58 :(